# Android application Can't access database for insert and update

Tags: java, android, sqlite, simplecursoradapter

I am developing notes application for Android, when I click the save button it is supposed to insert data to the db using the content provider method insert, after that the loader will automatically load the data, and the simplecursoradapter should populate that data. However, after clicking save nothing appears. It seems to me that the app can't access the database as I am getting this log when clicking the save button,

```
    02-27 12:31:31.112: E/SQLiteLog(13232): (257) Open fd: 74, file: /data/data/com.project.android.notes/databases/notes.db-journal
02-27 12:31:31.112: E/SQLiteLog(13232): (257) Close fd: 74
02-27 12:31:31.112: E/SQLiteLog(13232): (257) Open fd: 74, file: /data/data/com.project.android.notes/databases/notes.db-journal
02-27 12:31:31.186: E/SQLiteLog(13232): (257) Close fd: 74
02-27 12:31:31.271: E/SQLiteLog(13232): (257) Open fd: 80, file: /data/data/com.project.android.notes/databases/notes.db-journal
02-27 12:31:31.271: E/SQLiteLog(13232): (257) Close fd: 80
02-27 12:31:31.907: E/MCA(13851): Here call up the service!
02-27 12:31:31.908: E/MCA(13851): LT passed!
02-27 12:31:34.392: E/(180): AudioCloseDumpPCMFile file== NULL
02-27 12:31:34.392: E/(180): AudioCloseDumpPCMFile file== NULL
```

Content provider code:

```
    public class NotesProvider extends ContentProvider{

    // database
    private static TodoDatabaseHelper mdatabaseHelper;


    // used for the UriMacher
    private static final int NOTES = 10; //in case an entire table were requested to be returned.
    private static final int NOTES_ID = 20; //in case a specific item with a specific uri needs to be returned.




    //Let's build the UriMatcher:
    static UriMatcher sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH); //sUriMatcher: s stands for static, it is just a name.
    //when we initialize the UriMatcher we first say that it still has no matches. Let's assign the matches:
    //we do that in a static block, that's once the class is created the matches are built.
    static {

        sUriMatcher.addURI(NotesContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, NotesContract.NOTES_PATH, NOTES); //match an entire table.
        sUriMatcher.addURI(NotesContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, NotesContract.NOTES_PATH +"/#", NOTES_ID);


    }//end matching static block.


    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        //get a dbHelper obj,
         mdatabaseHelper = new TodoDatabaseHelper(getContext()); //why? Because this will help us retrieve a readable/writable db on which we can make operations like CRUD.
        return true; //we were successfully able to create an obj representation of the DB.
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        //here we should use the uri matcher to know how we can conduct the query.
        SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        queryBuilder.setTables(NotesContract.NotesTable.TABLE_TODO); //could be used for joins also.

        verifyColumns (projection); //verify if the columns are valid.
        int match= sUriMatcher.match(uri); //save the int associated with this uri in a var to be able to use it in the switch.
        Cursor cursor=null; //initialize cursor, it will be used to return the result of the query.
        SQLiteDatabase  db= mdatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase(); //we need this because we use an SQLiteQueryBuilder.
        switch (match) //start the switch
        {
            case NOTES:
                // call method query and send the params.
                cursor= queryBuilder.query(db,  projection, selection,
                       selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
                break; //don't go to next case.
            case NOTES_ID:
                //first initialize the where clause in the query builder:
                queryBuilder.appendWhere(NotesContract.NotesTable._ID + "=" + ContentUris.parseId(uri));
                //invoke the query method:
                cursor= queryBuilder.query(db,  projection, selection,
                        selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);

        }//end switch
        /*the queries above could be built using mSQLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase.query(..)*/
        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri); //very important and required, to update the ui when the data change.
        return cursor; //return the query result.
    }//end query.

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues) {
        int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        SQLiteDatabase db = mdatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        long id = 0;
        switch (match) {
            case NOTES:
                id = db.insert(NotesContract.NotesTable.TABLE_TODO, null, contentValues);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null); //notify observers about any update.
        return Uri.parse(NotesContract.NOTES_PATH + "/" + id);

}

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        SQLiteDatabase db = mdatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        int rowsDeleted = 0;

        switch (match) {
            case NOTES:
                rowsDeleted = db.delete(NotesContract.NotesTable.TABLE_TODO, selection, selectionArgs);
                break;
            case NOTES_ID:
                if (selection.isEmpty()){
                String whereClause= NotesContract.NotesTable._ID +  "=" + ContentUris.parseId(uri);
                rowsDeleted = db.delete(NotesContract.NotesTable.TABLE_TODO, whereClause, null);}

                else{
                    rowsDeleted = db.delete(NotesContract.NotesTable.TABLE_TODO,
                            NotesContract.NotesTable._ID + "=" + ContentUris.parseId(uri)
                                    + " and " + selection,
                            selectionArgs);
                }//end else
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }//end switch
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null); //if any delete happens notify the observers.
        return rowsDeleted;
    }//end delete


    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = mdatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase(); //return a writable obj from the db.
        int rowsUpdated = 0;
        int match= sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        switch (match) {
            case NOTES:
                rowsUpdated = db.update(NotesContract.NotesTable.TABLE_TODO,
                        contentValues,
                        selection,
                        selectionArgs);
                break;
            case NOTES_ID:
                long id = ContentUris.parseId(uri);
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
                    rowsUpdated = db.update(NotesContract.NotesTable.TABLE_TODO,
                            contentValues,
                            NotesContract.NotesTable._ID + "=" + id,
                            null);
                } else {
                    rowsUpdated = db.update(NotesContract.NotesTable.TABLE_TODO,
                            contentValues,
                            NotesContract.NotesTable._ID + "=" + id
                                    + " and "
                                    + selection,
                            selectionArgs);
                }
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return rowsUpdated;
    }

    private void verifyColumns (String [] cols) {
        //lets get the columns in the Db and compare.
        String[] existed = {NotesContract.NotesTable._ID, NotesContract.NotesTable.COLUMN_CATEGORY,
                NotesContract.NotesTable.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION,
                NotesContract.NotesTable.COLUMN_SUMMARY};
        if (cols != null) {
            ArrayList<String> existedCols = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(existed)); //this is how we convert an array to an arraylist.
            ArrayList<String> requestedCols = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(cols));
            // check if all columns which are requested are available
            if (!existedCols.containsAll(requestedCols)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Some columns don't exist in the database");
            }//end if.
        }//end outer if.
    }//end verification.

    public static Cursor searchDescription (String key)
    {
        String desc []= {"%"+key +"%"};
        SQLiteDatabase db = mdatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor rtCursor= db.rawQuery("select * from " + NotesContract.NotesTable.TABLE_TODO+ " where " +
                NotesContract.NotesTable.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " like ?", desc);

        return rtCursor;
    }//end searchDescription

}//end Provider.
```

Details activity code where the note is edited and saved:

```
 public class NotesDetails extends ActionBarActivity {

    private EditText noteSummary;
    private EditText noteDescription;
    private Spinner noteCategory;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final ContentResolver resolver = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notes_edit);

        Button saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.todo_edit_button);
         noteSummary = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.todo_edit_summary);
         noteDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.todo_edit_description);
         noteCategory= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.category);

        if (getIntent().getStringArrayExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)!=null){
        String [] receivedData=getIntent().getStringArrayExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);

            if (receivedData [0].equalsIgnoreCase("important")){
                noteCategory.setSelection(0);}//end if
            else {
                noteCategory.setSelection(1);} //end else
            noteSummary.setText(receivedData[1]);
            noteDescription.setText(receivedData[2]);

        }//end if (feasible only if the received intent contains an array of string, which happens if the user clicks onm one of the items in the simplecursoradapter view)


        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             String summary= null;
             String description= null;
             String category= null;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) { //this will happen every time you click the button.
               summary= noteSummary.getText().toString();
               description= noteDescription.getText().toString();
               category = noteCategory.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Toast toast ;
               if (summary.isEmpty()) {
                   toast = Toast.makeText(NotesDetails.this, "Summary cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                   toast.show();
               }
               else {
                   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                   values.put(NotesTable.COLUMN_CATEGORY, category);
                   values.put(NotesTable.COLUMN_SUMMARY, summary);
                   values.put(NotesTable.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, description);

                   //start inserting into the db via provider.
                   Uri uri =getContentResolver().insert(NotesTable.NOTES_URI, values);
                   Intent intent = new Intent(NotesDetails.this, NotesList.class);
                   startActivity(intent);
               }
            }//end onClick

        }); //end onClickListener

    }



}
```

Can anyone please tell me why this is happening and how to fix the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code.?

Answer (score 0):

Use this for insert

```
 public void onClickAddName(View view) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MyProvider.name, ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName))
                .getText().toString());
        Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(MyProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "New record inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've done something similar in the detailed activity, but it is not working. Can you please tell me what is the mistake I am doing?

Comment: done, I put only content provider code, and the code of the class from where I perform the insert query

Comment: Where you define this                 id = db.insert(NotesContract.NotesTable.TABLE_TODO, null, contentValues);What is null here?

Comment: When I checked different tutorials, I found that it is usually set to null

Comment: Give me your mail id i would like to send one small app.?

Comment: check your mail ID and remove your mail ID from here.